# Cocoa Accessibility API: Hide a window

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility

I'm looking to hide a window on OSX (not belonging to my app), but not the rest of the application. I have tried simply moving the window off the screen (like I would do in Windows), but the api always positions it at least 20 pixels away from the edge (#annoying).

Other things I have thought of:

- Setting the opacity of the window to zero (can this be done?)
- Minimizing the window, but it appears that the window handle becomes null once the window is minimized, so might be hard to get back
- Setting the window level (i.e. desktop) or z order (can this be done?)
- Moving the window to a different workspace (can this be done?)

Does anyone know of a way to do this?